# Linux headers wont install on VM unbutu 24

Tags: linux, terminal, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-headers

I need headers for a class and when I enter the command, I get this..[image]

I'm following the instruction given for my course and ive tried diffrent commands but the headers still wont show up [image]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: The error message says that the headers package is already installed.  There's no need to install it again.

Comment: For the reasons specified in both comments above mine, voting to close this.